# Why does blog.serverfault.com have a nice mobile interface, but blog.stackoverflow.com doesn't?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blog, blogging

Can this be looked at?

Also, on the subject of blog.*.com...any chance that they can be used to write articles of interest to the community...by the community? Perhaps a system where users (perhaps with n rep or more) can write an article, submit it, and then moderators go through and approve the posting on a somewhat regular basis...it would sure beat the occassional posting by Jeff about [random](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) [happenings](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/super-user-1-year-anniversary-super-contest/) [on Stack Exchanges](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/should-unix-linux-and-ubuntu-be-merged-vote/) (which would probably be better suited on a blog.stackexchange.com blog...). And if this happened, it would be nice if every new Stack Exchange got a blog.sename.com for announcements related to that particular exchange plus articles/postings by community members.

Comment: "  That would be awesome, your suggestion! I would love to learn from the experts and all! :) +1

Comment: Serverfault has a blog?!

Comment: Yes, ServerFault has a blog. SuperUser does not, though.

Answer (score 1):

Er.. what? Image upload support affects every site. The idea that we might merge some sites could affect every site. We might eventually offer periodic contests of some sort on every site.

I reject your premise as flawed.

edit: I addressed one of your dozen different questions embedded in this "question", by adding a mobile plugin to the wordpress blog.

Comment: I think that things that affect every site should be posted on blog.stackexchange.com. Things that affect a subset of sites can be cross-posted by the administrators/moderators/community leaders of the affected sites (if you don't use Ubuntu or Unix/Linux, you don't care that they might merge - but the results of the process might be of interest in the future). Contents for a given site should be posted on blog.thatstackexchange.com, since unless I'm a core user of that site, I don't care. Really, on the SO blog, there's more noise than content I care about from the perspective of an SO user.

Comment: Continued. When I view blog.someexchange.com, I expect to see things relevant to me as a user of that particular exchange, either in terms of features/changes or within some kind of community (programmer, power user, system administrator, mathematician, statistician, Unix/Linux user, etc.). But right now, the SO blog has things about Super User, Server Fault, Ubuntu, and Unix/Linux. If I truly cared about those sites, I would subscribe to their blog in my RSS reader. To be continued.

Comment: Finally, I think the community leaders of each exchange should decide how to notify their members about things. Every stack exchange supports the notification bars and has a Meta - both of these can be leveraged for announcements and to get community feedback on changes. The blog.stackexchange.com blog can be linked to in these to allow leaders to inform the community about happenings they feel are relevent to the site's users as well as post things that affect multiple communities. That, coupled with people subscribing or visiting the blogs and sites they care about should be sufficient.